# extract and compare integers from textline

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I want to search many .log files for a specific error occurence. The following shell code gives me the line I have to check for each .log file which states "Error termination" in its last 5 lines:

```
for f in *.log; do
  tail -n 5 "$f" | grep -q "Error termination" && tac "$f" | grep -m 1 "Step number"; 
done
```

This results in output like:

```
Step number  40 out of a maximum of  216
Step number  17 out of a maximum of  192
Step number  25 out of a maximum of  216
Step number 192 out of a maximum of  192
Step number  21 out of a maximum of  200
```

Each line corresponds to one .log file. Now I want to compare the two integers and print the file name only if the integers are the same.

Comment: Can you post sample of your log file (the last few lines)? Too much piping going on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line does exactly what I want, though there might be a much more elegant way with less pipes etc. .

```
for f in *.log ; do
  tail -n 5 "$f" | grep -q "Error termination" && tac "$f" | grep -m 1 "Step number" | grep -qo 'Step number \([0-9]*\) out of a maximum of  \1' && echo "$f";
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Just pass it via awk, like:

```
| awk '$3==$NF'
```

Comment: Is there a possibility to return only a True or False value by that awk code like -q for grep?

Comment: sure. exit(). like: `awk '$3==$NF {exit} {exit(1)}'`

Comment: When I use `| awk '$3==$NF {exit} {exit(1)}' && echo "$f"` it prints more lines than with `awk $3==$NF`only. Some of these files even don't contain "Step number". Do I misuse the boolean?